# Instanciar classe no parâmetro do método ou dentro do método

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, classes, método

Trabalhando com um controller do Laravel me deparei com algo similar a isso:

```
public function show(Role $role)
{
// é apenas um exemplo. 
}
```

Aonde a classe Role é instanciada na variável `$role` dentro do parâmetro do método, porem eu também posso instanciar a classe da seguinte maneira:

```
public function show()
{
   $role = new Role();
}
```

Aqui que vem minha duvida, qual seria a diferença entre essas duas formas de trabalhar, e a vantagem ente elas?

Comment: https://coredump.pt/questions/20171048/laravel-4-inversion-of-control tente ler isso.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers essa mais completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Instância por parâmetro

Desta forma no local onde for executado o método "show" é preciso passar como parâmetro o objeto "Role"

```
public function show(Role $role)
{
// é apenas um exemplo. 
}
```

## Objeto instanciado no próprio método

Enquanto que desta forma o objeto já esta sendo instanciado dentro do próprio método.

```
public function show()
{
   $role = new Role();
}
```

## Quando e como utilizar

A melhor forma vai depender do que você quer fazer, por exemplo, se você quer passar o objeto "Role" com algumas definições personalizadas toda vez que chamar o método "show" você teria que usar o primeiro método, já que em todos os momentos que você chamar "show" seria necessário passar o objeto "Role".

Por outro lado se o objeto "Role" tem o mesmo comportamento sempre que é chamado pelo método "show" é melhor usar o segundo método, já que a sua definição será a mesma.

Comment: Ai no caso seria é a Injeção de dependencia que no Laravel faz: https://coredump.pt/questions/20171048/laravel-4-inversion-of-control dê uma lida, para ficar completo... e essa mais completa: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vou da uma lida, obrigado!